# Unable to pass test case in React saying simulate a function onClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am working on Project on HackerRank where I have passed all the testcases except the simulate a function onClick or onSubmit.I dont know where I am going wrong because I have tried all the approach after refering documentation

Here is my code

**Mail.component**

```
export class Mail extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeMail: this.props.mail
        };
        this.handleCompose = this.handleCompose.bind(this);
    }

    handleCompose() {
    console.log("=========================Compose==================")
        this.props.storeComposeMail(this.props.inboxData);
    }

    render() {
         <div>
<NavLink
  className="composebtn"
  to="/composemail">

  <button onClick={this.handleCompose}
    className={
      "btn-success pull-right composebtn" +
      (this.props.folder == "draft" ? "" : " visible")}
 > Edit</button>

</NavLink>
    </div>
```

**MytestCase**

```
describe("without store", () => {
    let wrapper;
    const mockLoginfn1 = jest.fn();
    test("submit click event", () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(Mail.prototype, "handleCompose");
        var data = {
            id: "",
            from: "",
            to: "",
            subject: "",
            time: "",
            body: ""
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Mail
                storeComposeMail={mockLoginfn1}
                folder="inbox"
                inboxData={data}
                mail={1}
            />
        );

        const Button = wrapper.find("NavLink").at(0);
        Button.simulate("click");
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

**I am getting error like this**

```
FAIL  src/test/Mail.spec.js

  ● without store › submit click event

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)



    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.



      at Object.test (src/test/Mail.spec.js:61:21)

          at new Promise (<anonymous>)

      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)

          at <anonymous>
```

Kindly help me As I dont know function is not even getting triggered 
Any help will be appreceiated

Answer (score 0):

You have a click event on button not at `<NavLink />` component, so find the button and then simulate click on that button. This should solve your test.

```
describe('without Store', () => {
  it('Simulate click event', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Mail.prototype, 'handleCompose');
    const wrapper = mount(<Mail />);
    const Button = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
    Button.simulate('click');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Another thing I would like to add is, that testing states and class methods means we are testing the implementation details which is not necessary unless or until you have any business login involved in those methods or some transformations are been performed.

Comment: But I am doing code on hackerrank and I cant modify testcases provided by them so what alternative I should do in my component file to pass testcase

Comment: I dont know about hackerrank, but since they are simulating the click on <NavLink> what you can do is, pass the onClick prop in the NavLink component i,e. <NavLink onClick={this.handleCompose} >